# how to show the equivalence of density

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

How to show  $E$ is dense if and only if $int(\mathbb{R}- E) = \emptyset$

suggestions please.

I do not see how to  a direct proff

Comment: Do you know the theorem that in any space $X$, for any set $A\subseteq X$ we have $\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$?

Comment: Only I have to work on the topology of  $X=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The theorem is true in any space, including $\Bbb R$; do you know that $\operatorname{int}(\Bbb R\setminus A)=\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$? If not, proving that result is one way to get the result that you want.

Comment: that is the meaning of $ cl $????

Comment: $\operatorname{cl}A$ is the closure of $A$; another notation is $\overline{A}$.